# Eclipse does not show non java files

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to open non Java files in Eclipse. Sometimes java files will also show the same problem. After restart, I am still not able to view the contents of the file, but now there is an exception (Screenshot2). Also I could not find any similar problems while searching, so if this problem is a known problem, do let me know.emphasized text

Images available here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1rb4juVKAVkdhPp2s74c6L9u-ZMoM1UxM

Eclipse version is as follows (Copy pasted from About Eclipse):

Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers

Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800

(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2018.  All rights reserved. Eclipse and the Eclipse logo are trademarks of the Eclipse Foundation, Inc., https://www.eclipse.org/. The Eclipse logo cannot be altered without Eclipse's permission. Eclipse logos are provided for use under the Eclipse logo and trademark guidelines, https://www.eclipse.org/logotm/. Oracle and Java are trademarks or registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

This product includes software developed by other open source projects including the Apache Software Foundation, https://www.apache.org/.

Comment: Also tried to open with all the Editors that I get to see when Right Click --> "Open With" in Eclipse with the file selected .. but Eclipse staunchly refuses to show me the contents of the file.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of stack traces - your image doesn't show enough of the trace. Post the trace as text and include the whole trace.